# My Cookies won't save in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cookies

I've been messing around with this assignment and I'm pretty sure I'm about 90% done.

Everything is working properly but for some reason the Cookies just won't save.

When I enter information in the input fields and press submit, I get the alert that the code works. I ran it through some validation software and it said everything was validated and working. The HTML page I was given to code and verify the cookie (Not sure if I coded this right) says no cookies are saved.

I also used the developer command in FireFox to check saved cookie lists it says there are no saved cookies for this site. Any ideas?

Also while I'm here, the alert box pops up as soon as I load the page and when I click submit, how would I change it so it only pops up when I click submit?

Here is the Code: http://jsfiddle.net/384x5n4a/4/

```js
function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
  if (object.attachEvent)
    object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
  else if (object.addEventListener)
    object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}

function writeCookie(cName, cValue, expDate, cPath, cDomain, cSecure) {
  if (cName && cValue !== "") {
     var cString = cName + "=" + escape(cValue);
     if (expDate) 
        cString += ";expires=" + expDate.toGMTString();

     if (cPath) cString += ";path=" + cPath;
     if (cDomain) cString += ";domain=" + cDomain;
     if (cSecure) cString += ";secure";


     document.cookie = cString;
  }
  }

addEvent(window, "load", initPage, false);

  function initPage(){

    document.getElementById("sbutton").onclick = saveMailingInfo;
    console.log(document.cookie);



function saveMailingInfo() {

  var expire = new Date();
  expire.setFullYear(expire.getFullYear() + 3);

  var allFields = document.mailingForm.elements;
  for (var i  = 0; i < allFields.length; i++) {

    if (allFields[i].type == "text") {

      writeCookie(allFields[i].id, allFields[i].value, expire);

    }

    if (allFields[i].nodename == "SELECT") {

      writeCookie(allFields[i].id, allFields[i].selectedIndex, expire);

    }

    if (allFields[i].type == "radio" || allFields[i].type == "checkbox") {

  writeCookie(allFields[i].id, allFields[i].checked, expire);

}
  }
}
  alert("Cookie has been written!");
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- DW6 -->
<head>
<!-- 
-->
<title>Cakes by Emily</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="cakeForm.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
<div class="head" id="header">
  <p><img src="cake.jpg" alt="cake picture" /><img src="logo.gif" alt="Cakes by Emily" width="400" height="125" /></p>
  <div class="links" id="navigation">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Cakes</a>
    <a href="#">Pastries</a>
    <a href="#">Pies</a>
    <a href="#">Mailing List</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mainContent">
<p>Enter your info to be added to our email list with reminders about getting that birthday 
cake you want! Remember at Cakes by Emily, we aim to make every birthday the best!</p>
<form name="mailingForm" >
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
  First:

   </td>
   <td> <input type="text" name="firstName"  id="firstName"><BR>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
  Last: 
   </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" ><BR>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
  E-Mail: 

   </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" ><BR>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
  Birthday (mm/dd/yyyy): 

   </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="birthday" id="birthday" ><BR>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
  Favorite Cake: 

   </td>
   <td>
    <select id="favoriteCake">
     <option value="ButterCream">Butter Cream</option>
     <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
     <option value="Vanilla">Vanilla</option>
     <option value="RedVelvet">Red Velvet</option>
   </select><BR>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
  Frequency of Emails: 

   </td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="frequency" id="frequency1" >Email me monthly<BR>
       <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="frequency2" >Email me quarterly<BR>
       <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="frequency3" >Email me near my birthday<BR>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" id="sbutton" name="sbutton"  value="Join our mailing List" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset the form" />
</form>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your jsfiddle does nothing and you're calling the alert in the init method. try calling it inside the saveMailingInfo method

Comment: The reason your jsfiddle does nothing is because you have the JavaScript set to run onLoad, which means the load event has already fired. Change it to "in <head>". The alert needs to be moved up so it is inside the `saveMailingInfo()` function. After that it looks like it works: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2a333c7v/).

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think to do that. Thank you that worked. And I'll try and fix the jsfiddle.

Comment: Alright sweet thanks. But I see it writes the cookie but when I check the cookielist in FireFox it doesn't appear, why aren't they saving? Can't for the life of me figure it out.